# How does the Android compiler know where SuperHeroInfo.names should go if there is no onCreateView method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have some troubles understanding the code fragment in [this tutorial](http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/07/make-android-apps-12/).

My problem is that I don't understand the code inside `TitlesFragment.java` - the `onCreateView` method is missing, so how does the fragment know in which view `SuperHeroInfo.names` should lie?

Also I don't understand the code inside [DetailsActivity](http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/08/make-android-apps-13/) because of `android.R.id.content` (does this mean the full screen?).

Again my question is how does the app know where to put content inside of list adapter if the view isn't specified?

Comment: Do you mean this piece of code: ArrayAdapter<String> connectArrayToListView = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, SuperHeroInfo.NAMES);? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 is standard layout mapped one to one.

Comment: For me its more confusing the part that I don't understand where does he say where should the titles go. How can they just appear on screen without specifying inside which view they should be ? Is it because of class="com.newthinktank.derekbanas.fragmentlayout.TitlesFragment" inside of fragment_layout.xml ?

Comment: Because of this line android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, You need to check custom BaseAdapter https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: so basically this is a whole view ? How about android.R.id.content , what does it exacty mean I read its root element but root of what?

Comment: You shouldn't just post links to code - putting the actual code you are referring to in your question means that if your link dies, you question doesn't become meaningless. Please add any code you're referring to in the question itself, preferably as a [mcve].